# Prevent Text View from changing width and position when updating in an HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm following a SwiftUI tutorial and have made this view that updates with data when a user drags or zooms into an image. After I detoured from the tutorial to round these strings to the nearest hundredth, I noticed this behavior where the text is moving back and forth (and kind of clipping for a second) when it's updating the values. I've tried various combinations of the .frame, lineLimit, minimumScaleFactor modifiers to no avail. The behavior I want is for the system icons to not move and the text to be left aligned against them and then the Text frames should take up all the available space left (and not clip into the text when the text goes from 4 characters long to 5 characters long)

Current Behavior:
[image]

InfoPanelView.swift:

```
...
struct InfoPanelView: View {
    var scale: CGFloat
    var offset: CGSize
    
    @State private var isInfoPanelVisible: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "circle.circle")
                .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1) {
                    withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                        isInfoPanelVisible.toggle()
                    }
                }
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack(spacing: 2) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.left.and.arrow.down.right")
                Text(String(format: "%.2f", scale))
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "arrow.left.and.right")
                Text(String(format: "%.2f", offset.width))
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.and.down")
                Text(String(format: "%.2f", offset.height))
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .font(.footnote)
            .padding(8)
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .frame(maxWidth: 420)
            .opacity(isInfoPanelVisible ? 1 : 0)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Set a larger fixed width to each individual view.

Comment: thanks! that worked for the left alignment but I ended up needing alignment .leading in the frame (and not just multilineTextAlignment called with .leading)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a new subview:

```
struct ExpandingText: View {
    var value: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(String(describing: (0..<500).map{letter in letter}))
                .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
                .lineLimit(1)
            Text(String(format: "%.2f", value))
                .id(value)
                .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration:0)))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .frame(width: 75, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
}
```

The 500 character invisible string that's limited to 1 line ensures that the ZStack takes up as much width as that text ever could (so the icons no longer move) and the id modifier combined with making the transition override duration being 0 fixes the text box clipping issue.

Edit:
Adding a larger width frame with alignment set to .leading as per xTwisteDx's suggestion makes it left aligned as well